# Solaris 10, Shell Script, Cursor movement

Tags: shell-script, solaris, ksh

> ```
> #include <signal.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <sys/types.h>
> #include <time.h>
>
>
> void prtime() {
>         time_t rawtime;
>         struct tm * timeinfo;
>         char *s;
>
>         signal(SIGALRM, prtime);
>
>         time ( &rawtime );
>         timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
>
>         alarm (1) ; //printf("Time\n");
>         printf ( "\033[s\033[6;45H %s \033[u", asctime (timeinfo) );
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>         signal(SIGALRM, prtime);
>         alarm(1);
>         printf("continue instructions\n");
>         while (1) {
>                 pause();
>                 printf("continue instructions\n");
>         }
> }
> ```

I just try to write the clock at a specific position in terminal, but I want to save the cursor position before writing the clock, and then restore that position after writing the clock.

but the `\033[s` & `\033[u` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using commands `CSI s` and `CSI u` which have incompatible interpretations depending on the implementation.

The first one can be either "Save cursor position" or "Reset terminal emulator", the latter being a Solaris private interface.

You should use a library like ncurses to achieve portable screen handling but if you still want to hardcode the escape sequences, this might do what you expect:

```
printf ( "\0337\033[6;45H %s \0338", asctime (timeinfo) );
```